# Mapping Large Databases

Tags: schema, erd

I have the task of mapping a pretty large database schema (~250 tables). I can have Visio reverse engineer the database in pieces, but there are just too many tables to have it map the entire database. I know that SQL Server has the capability to map, but would it be able to map the entire thing? Is there other software out there meant to handle bigger databases?

Answer (score 1):

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3503223/how-to-generate-a-diagram-of-a-very-large-database-schema-sql-server) thread on stackoverflow had a lot of suggestions. Most of the time, mapping out the database is only going to work if you have the proper foreign key constraints already created.

I use Red Gate's tool that also digs up stored procedures that point and reference tables. It has diagrammed an instance for me that had over 9500 dependencies. (Tables, databases, views, functions, procedures, etc.) Although when you get to sizes that big, a diagram can only help so much and it's better to get a narrowed view.